# Select data from two tables with loop in mysql

Tags: mysql

I want to create a loop in mysql.

I have 2 tables, and I want to select all data from table A and result from table A for get data in table B.

For example CASE:

```
SELECT * FROM table_A;
```

Result:

```
Column_1  Column 2
-------------------
A         B
A1        B1
ABC       CDS
```

Query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table_B 
WHERE column = (...result from table_A....)
```

I want show all data using loop in mysql

```
CREATE PROCEDURE ROWPERROW()
BEGIN
DECLARE n INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE i INT DEFAULT 0;
SELECT * FROM table_A ;
SET i=0;
WHILE i<n DO 

............TABLE_B

END WHILE;
END;
;;
```

Comment: You could improve this question by adding sample data from table a and table b together with expected output.

Answer (score 0):

you could use an INNER JOIN  for obtain the result wit a single query

```
SELECT b.* 
FROM table_B b
INNER JOIN  table_A a ON a.column_1 = b.col1 and a.column_2 = b.col2
```